# How to create a layer with a gradient of values along a fixed distance?

Tags: arcgis-pro, weighted-overlay

Here is my issue. I have a polygon layer to which I have applied a risk value of 10/10 to enter into a Weighted Sum decision making process. At the boundary of this layer, rather than instantly go to 0 risk, I would like to create a buffer with a gradient of smoothly decreasing risk (10, 9.9, 9.8... 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0) maybe 1 km before the boundary to 1 km away from it.

I'm unsure how to achieve this, other than spending all day creating a separate buffer layer for each 0.1 transition.

Thanks